# Handling Firebase Data push notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to send a data type push notification from firebase to flutter app. As per documentation we need to handle these type of notification in order to show them in notification center. But there is no document which says how we can do this.

Is this feasible to handle Data type push notification in Flutter? Has anyone tried onbackgroundMessage function implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [official firebase_messaging library](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) to use push notification and you can find decent documentation there as well.
You can receive you data or notification payload like this,

> Define a TOP-LEVEL or STATIC function to handle background messages

```
 Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
   if (message.containsKey('data')) {
     // Handle data message
     final dynamic data = message['data'];
   }

   if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
     // Handle notification message
     final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
   }

   // Or do other work.
 }
```

> Set onBackgroundMessage handler when calling configure

```
 _firebaseMessaging.configure(
       onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onMessage: $message");
         _showItemDialog(message);
       },
       onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
       onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onLaunch: $message");
         _navigateToItemDetail(message);
       },
       onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
         print("onResume: $message");
         _navigateToItemDetail(message);
       },
     );
```

To show Local notifications use [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) this library,

```
var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel id', 'your channel name', 'your channel description',
    importance: Importance.Max, priority: Priority.High, ticker: 'ticker');

var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();

var platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
    androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0, 'plain title', 'plain body', platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: 'item x');
```

Comment: From myBackgroundMessageHandler , how to send the message to notification tray , with sound and custom buttons?

Comment: @max Check my edited my answer, and for more on local notification real [this](https://medium.com/@nitishk72/flutter-local-notification-1e43a353877b)